# Add object to array Google Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, google-cloud-firestore

Does somebody know how to add an object to an array in Google Firestore ? I've searched everywhere and tried a lot of things but nothing worked out. As you can see in the picture I'm using

```
const sendMessage = async (data, docID) => {
  const query = await db.collection("livestreams").doc(docID);
  const newDataObj = {
    created_At: data.created_At,
    displayName: data.displayName,
    message: data.message,
    ownerThumbnail: data.ownerThumbnail,
    userID: data.userID
  };
  const addObjToArr = await query.update({
    chat: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(newDataObj)
  });
};
```

But this only works for adding a basic value to the array. If I want to add an object this doesn't works and I can't find any solution online.

I'm using javascript/web.

[image: Adding object to array in Google Firebase]

Comment: As Renaud said: the way you're adding the object to the array looks correct. What doesn't work about it? Is there any relevant message showing in the console when the `query.update` runs?

Comment: I've already fixed it thanks to Renaud. The problem was that sometimes an undefined value was in the object and sometimes not depending on the input. The error came because of the undefined value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work. Note that you don't need to do `await db.collection("livestreams").doc(docID);` since [`doc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference?authuser=0#doc) is not asynchronous.

```
const sendMessage = async (data, docID) => {

   try {

      const query = db.collection("livestreams").doc(docID);  //<-- remove await
      const newDataObj = {
        created_At: data.created_At,
        displayName: data.displayName,
        message: data.message,
        ownerThumbnail: data.ownerThumbnail,
        userID: data.userID
      };
      const addObjToArr = await query.update({
        chat: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(newDataObj)
      });

    } catch (error) {
       console.log(error);
       // return something ...        
    }

};
```

---

**However, note four important points:**

1. The [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference?authuser=0#update) method works only if the document already exists. You may use [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference?authuser=0#set) with the [merge option](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.SetOptions?authuser=0) if your know your doc might not exist.
2. If you call twice the `arrayUnion()` method with the exact same object, no new array element is created.
3. Double check that your security rules allow the update.
4. Add a try/catch to check if you get an error.

Comment: https://ibb.co/JFRQMYR

This is my database, the array already exists. But it looks like I can't get an object into the chat array. Can you show me the code how you would fix it ?

Comment: The code should work if the doc already exists, as I mentioned. Any constraint with your security rules?

Comment: Just fixed it, thanks ! If you give an undefined value in the object it blocks. That was the main problem why it didn't work out.

Comment: Good news. I've adapted the answer with a `try/catch` block. Doing so will allow you to directly see an error message like : `FirebaseError: Function FieldValue.arrayUnion() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined`